# Minimax estimator for loss function

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1,.. X_n$ be IID Bernoulli(p) where we have a loss function $L(p, a)= {(p-a)^2}/{p}$and assume the prior is p is distributed with $Beta(\alpha, \beta)$. Find the MINIMAX estimator for this loss function.

I first tried to find the Bayes Rule which came out to be
$$A=\frac{a+\sum_{i=1}^n x_i-1}{a+b+n-1}$$ I then tried to let

$$E_p(\frac{(p-A)^2}{p})=C$$ and tried to find a, b such that the risk was constant but am struggling with the last step and would love some advice.

Comment: Are you mixing up $a,\alpha,A$ and $b,\beta$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $T(\boldsymbol X)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$, so that $T\sim \text{Binomial}(n,p)$. When $p\sim \text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$, the Bayes estimator of $p$ under the given loss function is

$$\hat p(\boldsymbol X)=\frac{\alpha+T-1}{\alpha+\beta+n-1} $$

So we seek a minimax estimator of $p$ of the form $cT+d$.

Note that

\begin{align}
E(cT+d-p)^2&=\operatorname{Var}(cT+d)+(E(cT+d-p))^2
\\&=c^2\operatorname{Var}(T)+(cE(T)+d-p)^2
\\&=c^2np(1-p)+(p(nc-1)+d)^2
\\&=c^2np-c^2np^2+p^2(nc-1)^2+2p(nc-1)d+d^2
\\&=p^2((nc-1)^2-nc^2)+p(nc^2+2ncd-2d)+d^2
\end{align}

So for $p\in (0,1]$, the risk of $cT+d$ is

$$\frac1pE(cT+d-p)^2=p((nc-1)^2-nc^2)+\frac{d^2}p+nc^2+2ncd-2d$$

For this to be free of $p$, you need $$(nc-1)^2-nc^2=0\quad,\quad d=0$$

Assuming $p\in (0,1]$, ignore one root of $c$ and you will get your minimax estimator. Finally equate the Bayes estimator and minimax estimator to solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$.